# C# : Store Generic List<> Objects to File Stream

Tags: c#, list, serialization, filestream

I have my `List<Employee>` object, I want to store this object to file stream. (Which would be not easily readable by human)

Also, I want to **retrieve** `List<Employee>` from stream to display list of employee on UI (I'm using .NET Windows Forms Application)

I also want to **update specific record in file steam**.
Could anybody please let me know that I would I do this?

If serialization is the only way to do this, please let me know how do I use it with regards to updating specific record information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going with Serialization, another option would be to go with a NoSql solution such as [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) or any of the ones listed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net).

Here is a [blog post](http://danielglyde.blogspot.com/2010/11/mvc-20-with-db4o.html) that talks about how to use db4o.  (based on mvc but could be used in a winform application as well.

This would allow you to leverage the power of linq to query your 5000 records easily and update the object without much trouble.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Do you have any idea about creating report (with Both windows based GUI based report and DosMatrix based report) without using any Sql DB. Im my win form application, I have NOT used any SQL related stuff, and still I want to create reports. Any idea and other ways will be really appreciated

Comment: If you are doing a lot of reporting you might get better performance from a SqlLite 4 option and using EF4.  It is really hard to say without some more context with your needs which is the best solution.  Possibly another question might help answer some of these questions with a bit more context.

Comment: There are NOT much reporting, but want to create fixed 10 types of reports, but as you know that I'm not using any SQL type of DB. I have data in my file stream. And I want to show report kind of UI to the Users where they can see the report (just like normal crystal report type of layout) and print the report. Please let me know if you have any idea or other ways to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

With serialization you'll have to deserialize the entire list and then serialize it back to perform an update operation.

If you don't want the output to be human-readable, `BinaryFormatter` is a way to go. However, if you really want to make it unreadable for random people, consider applying some encoding algorithm to your serialized data like RSA.

Example of using `BinaryFormatter` for serializing:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Create)) {
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, list);
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

And deserializing:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FileName)) {
try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var list = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

EDIT: changed the code examples a little

Comment: Thanks Dyppl! I want to know that if I store 5000 Employees data (e.g. List<Emplyee>) to file stream with Serializing it, How about the memory cost of operation, and Would be it a good way to do this?

Comment: Well, with those numbers you should at least consider using something more suited for such tasks like NoSql databases or SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org) assuming that you want to keep it in single file